# Bind without events in jQuery plugins

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to create a simple jQuery plugin, which when is imported, can bind every ".myspecialclass" class and add a new simple div into it. How Can I bind to ".myspecialclass" in this plugin without events or it is possible? If isn't possible, how can I expand my ".myspecialclass" with a new div when plugin is loaded?

THX.

Answer (score 4):

jQuery "plugins" is nothing but a prototype method attached to the instance. So when designing plugins, you can let the caller attach a jQuery collection of elements, f.ex:

```
$.fn.appendDiv = function() {
    return this.append('<div>');
};
```

And then call it with your selection of elements:

```
$('.myspecialclass').appendDiv();
```

Read more about plugin design here: http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/

If all you want is to append a `DIV` to all `.myspecialclass` onload, try:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('.myspecialclass').append('<div>');
});
```

...but this does not have anything to do with jQuery plugins.

Comment: I would like to avoid that caller attach the additional div. Can I avoid it somehow?

Comment: @VajdaEndre Eh, sorry... what?

Comment: I would like to append the new div from plugin automaticaly when is imported, without any function call. The original question was and still exist "how can I expand my ".myspecialclass" with a new div when plugin is loaded?" If it is possible than how?

Comment: @VajdaEndre How do you mean "imported"? How are you calling the "plugin"?

Comment: Sorry, imported mean loaded in this case ;). So "...when the plugin is loaded..." :)

Comment: THX. The last point is better now, but I've got another problem. If the user add another element with '.myspecialclass' class into DOM, after the plugin was loaded, this new element will not contain the new special div right? That was my original problem. I think its need to bind this new div somehow like an event, but I don't know that is possible or not? THX a lot.

Comment: @VajdaEndre You should post another question and be much clearer when describing your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you mean by bind the class to the plugin, but to expand you just need to create the div and append it to the targeted elements, like so:

```
var $div_el = $('<div />');

$('.myspecialclass').append($div_el);
```

as for the `$div_el` you can set attributes, text/html prior to adding them

Comment: I'd like to add this div from plugin. So when the plugin is loded every ".myspecialclass" class has another special div, when the plugin is not loaded every ".myspecialclass" class dont contains the special div. You know how it is possible from plugin?